# Consider two left join with same table SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query

```
left join 
    procedimentos on procedimentos.id = faturamento_lancamentos_bpa_adicionais.procedimento_id
left join 
    procedimentos on procedimentos.id = faturamento_lancamentos_bpa.procedimento_id
```

I need to consider procedimentos when faturamento_lancamentos_bpa_adicionais.procedimento_id and faturamento_lancamentos_bpa.procedimento_id

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to alias the "doubled" tables, as every entity needs a unique name

The use of meaningful aliases will keep also the query better readable

```
full Join faturamento_lancamentos_bpa_adicionais fat_adi ON 
fat_adi.faturamento_lancamento_bpa_id = 
faturamento_lancamentos_bpa.id

left join procedimentos proc1 on proc1.id = fat_adi.procedimento_id

left join procedimentos proc2 on proc2.id = faturamento_lancamentos_bpa.procedimento_id
```